# Azure Linux based VM could not start. Internal server error

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, azure, vhd

We have our own Linux based distribution for which we created a .vhd file from .iso using VirtualBox. We uploaded the .vhd to Azure following the instructions given here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-create-upload-vhd/ Then, we created a VM using this image, but when trying to start the VM, it fails. It gives the following error:

> 'The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.'

What can be the possible solution for this ?

Comment: That's really not much information to go on, as it's a generic error. If you can't find a more detailed error message, you might need to open a support ticket (which is outside the scope of ServerFault).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thats the whole problem, it gives out a generic error and there is no way to know whats going on. I cant open a support ticket as I'm trying it out on a free account. I posted it here coz if someone who has already faced this issue and resolved it, might be able to help me.